# Simulation photosystem light absorption in Quantum computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, photonics

[image]

Basically, I want to simulate the above photosystem process of light absorption. Above is a diagram of laser beams shot into antenna pigment molecules and traveling to the reaction center. Two theories surround the laser path: Random and shortest distance. The latter is more feasible.

[image]

My goal is to simulate the quantum effect behind this process regardless of which pigment molecule the light is being shot at. I came across this github repo on [Quantum programmable gate arrays](https://github.com/fancompute/qpga) so I want to know how to remodel it to simulate the above process.

Comment: The model you are proposing looks like a semi-classical scattering/absorption probability model. There is no need for quantum mechanics for such a low level description. A simple Monte-Carlo algorithm will do.

Comment: @FlatterMann Can I get more insight on that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method